# Cordova: iOS: console.log not logging anything in Xcode

Tags: ios, cordova, plugins, push-notification, ionic-framework

On iOS, console.log rarely works (nothing gets printed to console in Xcode)

Here are my config files. Please let me know if I should add something to help debug these issues.
https://gist.github.com/adaptivedev/d33f38cd3d6cf10be9dc

I'm on OSX 10.9.4 with XCode 5.1.1, cordova 3.5

Thanks!